# Выход за границы массива в python

Tags: python, массивы

У меня есть массив данных. Использую его, чтобы проверить правильность коэф-ов.

```
summ1=0
N=2
for m in range(N):
    for k in range(size):
        if k+2*m > (size-1):
            vol1[k+2*m]=0
        summ1+=vol1[k]*vol1[k+2*m]
```

Если номер элемента выходит за границу массива, то нужно вернуть 0 вместо **vol1[k+2*m]**. Допустим размерность массива 5. А k+2*m=100 и понятно, что такого элемента нет, и нужно **vol[100]** присвоить значение **0**

Я попробовал реализовать в следующем коде, но ничего не вышло. Прошу помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться конструкцией if else

```
for m in range(N):
    for k in range(size):
        n = k+2*m
        summ1 += vol1[k]*(vol1[n] if n < len(vol1) else 0)
```